# I can't higlight cell in Excell from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, background

I have an issue with my code to highlight specific cell in an excel file when I export my DF. Cells to highlight with background colors are outliers of the column. Oultiers are calculated thanks a for loop on each column.

Here the code where I calculate outliers for each column:

```
for col in dfmg.columns.difference(['Sbj', 'expertise', 'gender']):
Q1c = dfmg[col].quantile(0.25)
Q3c = dfmg[col].quantile(0.75)
IQRc = Q3 - Q1
lowc = Q1-1.5*IQR
uppc = Q3+1.5*IQR
```

Then I created this function to define how to higlight cells:

```
def colors(v):
for v in dfmg[col]:
    if v < lowc or v > uppc:
        color = 'yellow'
return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

And I apply my function to a new df:

```
df_colored = dfmg.style.applymap(colors)
```

The problem is that when I export df_colored, everything is yellow! Where am i wrong?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create DataFrame of styles and apply to DataFrame, I modify your solution for no loops:

```
def hightlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    cols = x.columns.difference(['Sbj', 'expertise', 'gender'])
    Q1 = x[cols].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = x[cols].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    low = Q1-1.5*IQR
    up = Q3+1.5*IQR
    mask = x.lt(low) | x.gt(up)
    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #modify values of df1 column by boolean mask
    df1[cols] = df1[cols].mask(mask, c1)
    return df1

dfng.style.apply(hightlight, axis=None)
```